# javascript get href address and change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

i need to get href value and change it and open in new tab Automatically.

Address tag in the page.

```
<a href="http://xxxxx/first_123.html" id="view-1" class="view button_green" style="margin: 10px;">view</a>
```

I want to get `http://xxxxx/first_123.html` address with JavaScript and Change to

```
http://xxx/second_123.html
```

And then Open `http://xxx/first_123.html` In new tab Automatically.

I Use Greasemonkey. Thanks.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to ask a question, or indeed show us the code you're having trouble getting working

Comment: Thanks freefaller. I have <a href="http://xxxxx/first_123.html" id="view-1" class="view button_green" style="margin: 10px;">view</a>
i want to get href value and change to http://xxxxx/second_123.html
and then open second in tew tab.

Comment: At the risk of it being automatically deleted by the system, I would suggest you read the following website before asking questions on StackOverflow:  http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<a href="http://xxxxx/first_123.html" id="view-1" class="view button_green" style="margin: 10px;">view</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#view-1").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var _curr_href= $(this).attr("href");
        $(this).attr("href", _curr_href.replace("first", "second"));
        window.open(_curr_href);
      });
});
```